# Job offer via email now changed

Tags: job-offer

I was given a position in a school and handed notice in many weeks ago.  I am due to leave the current position this week.

I was taken on as a full time TA. Now the week I leave my current position I've been told I am now only being taken on "At the moment, due to budgetary considerations, we are only able to offer you a casual appointment".

Can they do this ???? When original email offering me position was for full time position.

Comment: Did you sign a contract with them?

Comment: If the email is not a signed agreement, then they may change it depending on your location. Which country are you in ? Please add the country tag to your post

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, we need a lot more details here, in particular jurisdiction and whether you actually signed a contract or not (a offer letter is not binding!).

But it honestly doesn't matter too much - even in a jurisdiction with relatively strong workers' rights like the UK<sup>1</sup>, they can always make you redundant. They *might* owe you whatever the notice period is in your contract, but that doesn't help you much. If you didn't sign a contract, they owe you nothing.

<sup>1. strong compared with places like the US anyway.</sup>

Comment: See also past discussion such as the recent https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/195258/can-my-employer-change-my-1099-contracted-pay-rate-without-my-acceptance-or-a-ne